# Cannot change resolution with 8th Gen Intel CPU in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution

All

I just install a fresh new Ubuntu 16.04 on my new desktop which has a 8th generation Intel CPU i5 8600K. When OS installed, I found there is only one option in display setting: 1024 x 768 (4:3),

My monitor is a HDMI monitor with 1920x1080 resolution

Do anyone have any idea how to make the resolution setting right? Thanks.

BTW. I do not install any graphic card, I use the internal GPU of Intel

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with an i7-8700K and 3440x1440 Samsung panel over HDMI or dP. It was working with the previous i7-6700K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All. I fix this issue with upgrading linux kernel to 4.15 which support coffee lake GPU

Answer (score 4):

This is what helped me on 17.10 with an i3-8100 and 4k monitor, should work on 16.04 too.

1. Do `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` or use any other editor.
2. Find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line and add `i915.alpha_support=1` to its value. It'll look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1"`
3. `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

I've read somewhere we won't need alpha_support in 18.04.

Comment: So I guess Intel were a bit late to finish testing/integrating their Coffee Lake linux driver support, and we have to use the alpha support mode to properly use 8th gen with Ubuntu. Would that be more or less it?

Comment: Just worked for me, on Ubuntu 16.04 indeed.