# Max resolution of Intel 8th gen Integrated graphics undetected by Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, display-resolution

On a newly installed 16.04, the screen resolution cannot be changed from 1024 x 768, even though my Intel chipset and monitor are confirmed to support a resolution of 1920 x 1200 or more.

I do seem to have the Intel driver installed and enabled. I have also tried [the Intel update tool](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/intel-graphics-update-ubuntu-16-04), which didn't change anything.

I have seen quite a few questions about it here and elsewhere, none of which suggest a clear solution nor any way of diagnosing the root cause. My current bet is that somehow 8th generation intel processors, require [Coffee Lake support enabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417288/problem-with-screen-resolution-on-debian-buster-coffee-lake-processor) but the process seems a little sensitive to try.

Comment: So I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002662/208696) should solve it, but have to defer to a time when I can handle the worst case scenario of the implied tinkering.

Comment: Coffee Lake support was added to the Linux 4.13 kernel in late 2017, over 1.5 years after Ubuntu 16.04 was released. Try LiveUSBs of 17.10 and even 18.04 (Warning: Pre-Release, not finished) to see if the issue is resolved in more recent releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: Many thanks for mentioning the timeline there. I guess would be nice if anyone confirmed the status of the issue on 17.04 at some point. Meanwhile I use the alpha supported intel driver as in my answer below.

Comment: @user535733 The [16.04 HWE kernel is 4.13](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kernel/linux-generic-hwe-16.04).

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, true...but *if* the OP is using 4.13, it's not working anyway.

Comment: @user535733 A "newly installed 16.04" won't have HWE.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, true. That's why I didn't go down that road.

Comment: What's HWE actually?

Comment: @matt Hardware Enablement. See the wiki: [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved by switching to an alpha-supported version of the intel driver (hopefully full/standard support coming soon or in the next LTS versions, but I guess this is what we have now for 16.04). It also solved the display looking slightly fuzzy and made resuming from system suspend work.

[Follow the exact steps here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989946/cannot-change-resolution-with-8th-gen-intel-cpu-in-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1) to accomplish the same, and hope this alpha support doesn't hurt you elsewhere. Actually they note there, that 17.04 is equally lacking default support.

One reason more to never buy the latest intel CPU generation.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other. Don't forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: I think I did upvote, any special reason you're saying that? about duplicates ― I find the management of duplicates quite arcane and badly managed, really, SO should do something about it using today's ease of machine learning.

Comment: The special reason is that your answer does not contain actual instructions, so it is a border case to [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). If you’ve got any ideas on improving the management of duplicates, please post them on [meta] or [meta.se]!

Comment: Unfortunately Meta Stack Exchange is very hostile and narrow-minded, I doubt I'd ever pursue anything there again. I think my answer a) adds some information and b) provides a more generalized title, or an augmenting title, compared to the one linked to, and should therefore be made useful by the SO platform. I realize that is not the case right now, but can't think of a way to resolve that given the relative hostility of the Meta channel.